# JavaScript identity operator on strings

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a prototype for determining if a string is empty. It's really just playing with JS and prototype, nothing important. Here's my code:

```
String.prototype.IsEmpty = function() {
  return (this === "");
}
```

Notice I used the `===` identity comparison instead of `==` equality. When I run the function with the above definition:

```
"".IsEmpty(); // false
```

If I chagne the definition to use `==` as:

```
String.prototype.IsEmpty = function() {
  return (this == "");
}
```

The new def'n will do:

```
"".IsEmpty(); // true
```

I don't understand why `===` doesn't work since `""` is identical to `""`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because `""` is a string primitive, but when you call `.IsEmpty()` it's implicitly converted to a `String` object.

You'd need to call .toString() on it:

```
String.prototype.IsEmpty = function() {
  return (this.toString() === "");
}
```

Interestingly this is browser-specific - `typeof this` is `string` in Chrome.

As @pst points out, if you were to convert the other way and compare `this === new String("");` it still wouldn't work, as they're different instances.

Comment: I was just thinking about that -- String vs. string. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 9):

=== is *identity* (same object; x is x**). == is *equality* (same value; x looks like y).

Lets play some (Rhino / JS 1.8):

```
{} === {} // false
new String("") === new String("") // false
typeof new String("") // object

"" === "" // true
typeof "" // string
f = function () { return "f" };
"foo" === f() + "oo" // true

String.prototype.foo = function () { return this; };
typeof "hello".foo() // object -- uh, oh! it was lifted
```

So, what just happened?

The difference between a String object and string.  Of course, the equality compare (or .length) should be used.

The [proof in the pudding](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), section 11.9.6 discusses the === operator algorithm

Comment: Would also add that 0, false, "", null and sometimes undefined match with equality operations, which can cause some head scratching.